# CouchDB view to find users via case-insensitive email

Tags: php, curl, couchdb, cloudant

I have a CouchDB view in my _user database, where I can find users based on their email addresses (`user.email` is part of their user doc).

```
{
  "_id": "_design/find-user",
  "views": {
    "email->doc": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit(doc.email, doc);\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

I am using the following curl url via PHP to access matching users:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/_users/_design/find-user/_view/email->doc?key="' . $email . '"');
```

This works, but is case sensitive, which I don't want. For example, I need `$email = TesT@example.com` to find `tESt@example.com` in my database.

I have tried the following, but that only transforms the output.

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.email.toLowerCase(), doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `toLowerCase()`. The only piece you're missing is that you must also transform your search term.

Don't search for `"TEST@example.com"`, instead search for `strtolower("TEST@example.com")`:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/_users/_design/find-user/_view/email->doc?key="' . strtolower($email) . '"');
```

Comment: Thanks :) I need it case-insensitive in all directions though. So TesT@example.com must find tESt@example.com etc. Sorry for having been more specific, I will update my original post

Comment: Yes. My answer provides that.

Comment: Oh wow it does! Does that mean that `test` finds `TEST`, but `TEST` doesn't find `test`? Why would that be?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. By normalizing to lowercase on both ends, you get a case-insensitive match, regardless.

Comment: I was thinking the emit function only transforms output AFTER a doc is found. But I guess it transforms all docs BEFORE the lookup? Then it makes sense :) Thanks so much!

Comment: The `emit` function is used to build the index that is then searched for the key you provide.